# Redesign the submenu of drop down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In my wp based website I have a dropdown menu ,the sub menu inherit all the properties from root menu . If a submenu item has larger text it splits into two line . Like under services menu the submenu software development is splited in two line

_Software

Developemt_

I want to fit it one line like "software development"

I tried this

```
ul#mainmenu-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  padding:2px;
}

ul#mainmenu-menu ul.sub-menu > li {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-weight: normal;


}
ul#mainmenu-menu ul.sub-menu > li > a {
  height: auto;

  line-height: 10px;
  padding:2px;  
}
```

but didn't work . How can I fix it .

my working site http://aniyanetworks.net/Blog/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use

```
ul#mainmenu-menu ul.sub-menu li a {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It is now in one line , but a new problem occurred. Now the text goes out of the box , how can I resize the width of submenu ?

Comment: Just increase padding or give a width